# Optimizing an RDLC report

Tags: rdlc

I am using RDLC Reports and the report viewer control, and I am seeing that the more records there is in the final result the longer it takes to load.
It sounds to me that the RDLC report loads all records at once (and caches them locally) even though it paginates it when sending to the browser.
So I believe the solution should be to cause the report to load only the records needed for the current page.
How can I do this?
Or if there is another solution to optimize then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

If you need to analyze and aggregate a huge amount of records (millions) you can do the work on sql server using a Stored Procedure or a Query and next you can output to the report viewer only the aggregated data.

This is useful when you don't need to show the details of your data in your report.